# Move keys of an objects by his name in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I actually have a problem, it's been like 3 days, that I'm searching how to move the keys of an object by his name, and if no value has been given, get the first value of the object.

But, the problem is that I don't find any answer, could you please help ?

And, I don't want to use jQuery or any library, all in plain native JS
Here is the JS code :

```
window.onload = function(){
    var uberTable = document.querySelector('.divTable');
    for(var i in users){
        showDatas(uberTable, users, i)+'<br>';
    }
    var keys = document.querySelector('.headRow');
    showColumns(keys, users, i);
    replaceFirstColumn(users, 3, 0);
};

function showDatas(id, table, iterator){
    id.innerHTML += '<div class="divRow">'+
    '<div class="divCell">'+
    table[iterator].Name + '&nbsp</div><div class="divCell">' +
    table[iterator].Email + '&nbsp</div><div class="divCell">' +
    table[iterator].Gender + '&nbsp</div><div class="divCell">' +
    table[iterator].Age + '&nbsp</div><div class="divCell">' +
    table[iterator].Company +'</div>'
    '</div>';
}

function showColumns(id, table, iterator){
    var obj = Object.keys(table[iterator])
    for(var k in obj){
        id.innerHTML += '<div class="divCell">'+obj[k]+'</div>';
    }
}
```

The Datas :

```
var users = [
    {
      "Name": "Random name",
      "Email": "user@email.com",
      "Gender": "Male",
      "Age": 33,
      "Company": "SUPCompany",
    },
    {
      "Name": "username",
      "Email": "User@email.ca",
      "Gender": "Male",
      "Age": 44,
      "Company": "GolemAi",
    },
    {
      "Name": "Different name",
      "Email": "random@user.ca",
      "Gender": "Male",
      "Age": 23,
      "Company": "SUPCompany",
    },
    {
      "Name": "Nicolas Sarkozy",
      "Email": "niconico@unemployed.prison",
      "Gender": "Male",
      "Age": 50,
      "Company": "Unemployed",
    },
    {
      "Name": "No Idea",
      "Email": "No@Id.ea",
      "Gender": "Female",
      "Age": 20,
      "Company": "The Random Company",
    },
    {
      "Name": "Brigitte Macron",
      "Email": "Brigitte@elysee.dz",
      "Gender": "Female",
      "Age": 180,
      "Company": "Mummy of Manu'",
    },
    {
      "Name": "Corentin Crésus",
      "Email": "tintin@cre.sus",
      "Gender": "Polygender",
      "Age": 500,
      "Company": "Crésus LGBT Corp",
    },
  ];
```

Here is the CSS Code for the table :

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Marcellus');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
body{font-family: 'Roboto', 'Marcellus'}

.divTable
{
    display: table;
    width: auto;
    background-color: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-spacing: 5px;
    border-collapse: separate;
}

.headRow{font-weight: bold}
.headRow > .divCell{background: cyan}

.divRow > .divCell:nth-child(1){
    background: cyan;
    font-style: italic;
}

.divRow
{
   display: table-row;
   width: auto;
}

.divCell
{
    float: left;
    display: table-column;
    text-align: center;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    border-style: ridge;
    border-width: 1px;
}
```

And the HTML Code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Uber Table</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="divTable">
        <div class="headRow"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="db.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _"how to move the keys of an object by his name"_: can you be clearer by what you mean by this? Perhaps provide an expected output?

Comment: You need to explain more... The code is even more complicated than the question...

Comment: Actually, if I precise a key, like "Gender" or "Company", I want to put it as the first key, and display it as the first data in a table

Comment: So you want a list of all the names, a list of all the emails and so on ?

Comment: @DobromirM in fact, I already displayed all the datas in a table. Now, if I precise in Javascript which key I want as first data presented in the table, it will show it as the first datas in the table

Comment: Can you show us the code for that table so we can get a better understanding of it?

Comment: Sure @DobromirM it's added

Comment: I still cannot understand what exactly you are trying to achieve.
The only thing that comes to mind is that you are trying to make ordering of the table?
Here is a js fiddle with your current code: https://jsfiddle.net/jm1sw7ya/1/

Comment: @DobromirM yes, I want to order the keys of the table by putting a precised key as the first element of the table

Comment: So for example if you select 'Gender' that should become the first column of the table?

Comment: Yup ! That's totally that @DobromirM !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this function:

```
function replaceFirstColumn($firstColIndex = 3, $replacedColIndex = 0){
    var tableRows =  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.divRow, .headRow'));

    tableRows.forEach(function(element) {
        var rowCells = Array.from(element.getElementsByClassName('divCell'));

        var aux = rowCells[$firstColIndex].innerHTML;

        rowCells[$firstColIndex].innerHTML =  rowCells[$replacedColIndex].innerHTML;
        rowCells[$replacedColIndex].innerHTML = aux;         
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. AFAIU you are learning javascript and you need a simple code so you can understand at your current level. So I tried to change your code the least I could.

```js
var users = [ { "Name": "Random name", "Email": "user@email.com", "Gender": "Male", "Age": 33, "Company": "SUPCompany", }, { "Name": "username", "Email": "User@email.ca", "Gender": "Male", "Age": 44, "Company": "GolemAi", }, { "Name": "Different name", "Email": "random@user.ca", "Gender": "Male", "Age": 23, "Company": "SUPCompany", }, { "Name": "Nicolas Sarkozy", "Email": "niconico@unemployed.prison", "Gender": "Male", "Age": 50, "Company": "Unemployed", }, { "Name": "No Idea", "Email": "No@Id.ea", "Gender": "Female", "Age": 20, "Company": "The Random Company", }, { "Name": "Brigitte Macron", "Email": "Brigitte@elysee.dz", "Gender": "Female", "Age": 180, "Company": "Mummy of Manu'", }, { "Name": "Corentin Crésus", "Email": "tintin@cre.sus", "Gender": "Polygender", "Age": 500, "Company": "Crésus LGBT Corp", }, ];   

onload = function(){
     var uberTable = document.querySelector('.divTable');
     for(var i in users){
         showDatas(uberTable, users, i, 'age');
     }
     var keys = document.querySelector('.headRow');
     showColumns(keys, users, i, 'Age');
};

function showDatas(id, table, iterator, first){
     id.innerHTML += '<div class="divRow">'+
     '<div class="divCell ' + (first == 'name' ?   'first' : '') +  '">'+
     table[iterator].Name + '</div><div class="divCell ' + (first == 'email' ?   'first' : '') +  '">' +
     table[iterator].Email + '</div><div class="divCell ' + (first == 'gender' ?   'first' : '') +  '">' +
     table[iterator].Gender + '</div><div class="divCell ' + (first == 'age' ?   'first' : '') +  '">' +
     table[iterator].Age + '</div><div class="divCell ' + (first == 'company' ?   'first' : '') +  '">' +
     table[iterator].Company +'</div>' +
     '</div><br>';
}

function showColumns(id, table, iterator, first) {
    var obj = Object.keys(table[iterator])
    for(var k in obj){
        id.innerHTML += '<div class="divCell ' + (first == obj[k] ?   'first' : '') +  '">'+obj[k]+'</div>';
    }
}
```

```css
.divRow, .headRow {
  width: 100%;
}

.divCell {
  display: inline;
  border-left: solid 1px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.first {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="headRow">
</div>
<br>
<div class="divTable">
</div>
```

The code above can be written in a much more advanced way. Here is a more advanced version for use you are ready.

```js
var users = [ { "Name": "Random name", "Email": "user@email.com", "Gender": "Male", "Age": 33, "Company": "SUPCompany", }, { "Name": "username", "Email": "User@email.ca", "Gender": "Male", "Age": 44, "Company": "GolemAi", }, { "Name": "Different name", "Email": "random@user.ca", "Gender": "Male", "Age": 23, "Company": "SUPCompany", }, { "Name": "Nicolas Sarkozy", "Email": "niconico@unemployed.prison", "Gender": "Male", "Age": 50, "Company": "Unemployed", }, { "Name": "No Idea", "Email": "No@Id.ea", "Gender": "Female", "Age": 20, "Company": "The Random Company", }, { "Name": "Brigitte Macron", "Email": "Brigitte@elysee.dz", "Gender": "Female", "Age": 180, "Company": "Mummy of Manu'", }, { "Name": "Corentin Crésus", "Email": "tintin@cre.sus", "Gender": "Polygender", "Age": 500, "Company": "Crésus LGBT Corp", }, ];   

onload = function(){
    showDatas('Age');
    showColumns('Age');
};

function showDatas(first){
    users.map((user)=> document.querySelector('.divTable').innerHTML += 
        '<div class="divRow">' + 
        Object.keys(user).reduce((acc, key)=>
            acc +='<div class="divCell ' + (first == key ?   'first' : '') +  '">'+  user[key] + '</div>', '') + 
        '</div><br>')
}

function showColumns(first) {
    Object.keys(users[0]).map((col)=>
        document.querySelector('.headRow').innerHTML += 
            '<div class="divCell ' + (first == col ?   'first' : '') +  '">' + col + '</div>');
}
```

```css
.divRow, .headRow {
  width: 100%;
}

.divCell {
  display: inline;
  border-left: solid 1px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.first {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="headRow">
</div>
<br>
<div class="divTable">
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, what you've done is really great, and I understand it really well (and yeah, i'm a JSC starter ^^) !
But, I want to use the `display:table` method as I showed in my exemple. With the code you gave me, it don't works with `display:table`.
But thank you, it also works

Answer (score 0):

```js
let users = [
    {
      "Name": "Yanis Bendahmane"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Killian Vermersch"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Neil Richter"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Nicolas Sarkozy"
    },
    {
      "Name": "No Idea"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Brigitte Macron"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Corentin Crésus"
    }
  ];


const GET_USER_NAMES = list => {
  return list.map(i => i['Name']).join()
}

let tmpl = `<div>${GET_USER_NAMES(users)}</div>`

console.log(tmpl)
```

Here we loop over your users with the `GET_USER_NAMES` method and return a string of the individual Object' `Name` props and then using [ES6 template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to place that list String into a div.

You could then place that `tmpl` string variable as your content to append to the page.

*note* I've shortened the users obj array for readability.

As mentioned in the comments, its not super clear what you are expecting but i've tried my best.